# Serialize Map to Object with alias in object property

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, objectmapper

I'm trying to serialize a LinkedHashMap to a specific object. But my property in that object has a different name, how can i match these properties in the correct way?
I tried to use @JsonValue and @JsonProperty annotations but my property value on the class always null.

I Have this map:

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
myMap.put("user_name", "John Doe");
```

And i want to serialize to this Object:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public static class DummyUser {
    private String userName;
}
```

I'm trying to use this approach:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
mapper.convertValue(myMap, DummyUser.class);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to apply a mapping config to your POJO, specifically at setter method of userName:**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public static class DummyUser {
    private String userName;

    @JsonProperty("user_name")
    public setUserName(String un) {...}
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Map<String, String> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
myMap.put("user_name", "John Doe");

mapper.readValue(myMap, DummyUser.class);
```

Comment: It was my mistake with the @JsonProperty. In my first test I was using the import
"com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty" and did'n work, now i used your solution with the import "org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty" and it worked! Thanks!